# KeeWeb fails: the name org,freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files on nixos

Tags: linux, nix, nixos

I am trying to get KeeWeb working in Nixos.
It is not in the 20.09 channel, and so I tried writing a derivation for it... and failed. Luckily after some more searching I found out someone else had already done it ! Wonderful!

So I copied the code from : https://github.com/sikmir/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/applications/misc/keeweb/default.nix . And imported it into my home manager setup. It builds fine but when I run it it only opens an error dialog:

"Error loading app. Error: the name org,freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files"

A bit of seaerching points me into the direction of gnome-keyring and libsecret. Even a PR that addresses this issue, so you would think its fixed... but alas.

I changed the src to point to the latest version, but still no luck.

So probably something I am missing on my setup.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Could be a problem with your backport or with the way home-manager integrates it into your home profile. You could upgrade your system and your home-manager to nixos-unstable to test it with home manager. (and switch back to 20.09 afterwards if you prefer)

Comment: I tried that, but then the whole i3 stops working nicely so I do not want to be there :) What you exactly mean by those two options is not clear to me though. Is there somthing I can do to investigate it better? I tried adding libsecret and gnome to home.pkgs but that did not do anything.

Comment: In that case I'm out of ideas. Perhaps nixos-unstable includes a fix for a dependency that keeweb needs. If that's the case and it's not easy to find, you may be better off fixing i3 on master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable gnome-keyring daemon in your NixOS configuration:

```
services.gnome3.gnome-keyring.enable = true;
```

Comment: Grea, that did it! I was not far off seeing something to do with gnome-keyring, but did not know how toput the pieces together. thx.